# OCaml syntax error - fun pattern matching

Tags: ocaml

Here is my code :

```
let rec mul = fun 
|a b when a mod 2 = 0 -> mul (a/2) (2*b)
|a b when a mod 2 = 1 -> mul ((a-1)/2) (2*b)+b;;
```

It's telling me syntax error on line 2. 
I must say that I don't see why, I am just doing a simple double parameter pattern matching ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fun` keyword takes a series of patterns, each of which represents one argument. So, any number of arguments with one pattern each.

The `function` keyword takes a series of patterns separated by "|", representing alternatives for a single argument. So, one argument with any number of patterns for it.

You have something else, a mixture of the two. Note that there is no single pattern like "a b". It works with `fun` because a and b are separate patterns.

You can write your function like this:

```
let rec mul = fun a b ->
    if a mod 2 = 0 then mul (a/2) (2*b)
    else mul ((a-1)/2) (2*b)+b
```

(But most likely you knew this and were just interested in the pattern matching aspect.)

Comment: Thank you ! Can you please provide an example with fun ?